# How to extract text from specific rows in nested tables with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to extract text from a website, and I can't figure out how to properly get specific rows  of data in nested tables. I need to get the plain text after the parts that say **Property Address:** and **Mailing Address:**, so I can store the data.

Here is the HTML source I am parsing:

```
<table width="730" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr> 
    <td><table width="730" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
      <tr> 
        <td><h1>Property Information</h1>
          <table width="758">
            <tr>[IRRELEVANT]</tr>
            <tr>[IRRELEVANT]</tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"><strong>Property Address:</strong>&nbsp;!!THIS PLAIN TEXT HERE IS WHAT I NEED!! DATA1</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"><strong>Mailing Address:</strong>!!NEED THIS TOO!! DATA2</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>[IRRELEVANT]</tr>...................
```

I was using this as a template, but it doesn't work, and I have no idea how to make it work.

```
Document documentSerialNumberPageData = Jsoup.connect(stringURLOfSerialNumberPage).get();   //connect to serial number page
Elements elementsSerialNumberPageData = documentSerialNumberPageData.select("#tabletext tbody > tr > td > tbody > tr > td > tbody > tr > td");  //this is not even remotely correct... :(
Element elementAddress = elementsSerialNumberPageData.get(0);
System.out.println(elementAddress.text());
```

My knowledge of HTML/CSS is very limited, but I'm proficient in Java. Any suggestions? Thanks!
Full Source Here: https://github.com/PhotonPhighter/NODScraper/blob/master/src/nodscraper/Main.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Elements innerTable = documentSerialNumberPageData.select("body > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(2)");
String propertyAddress = ((org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode)innerTable.select("tr:nth-child(3) > td > strong").first().nextSibling()).text();
String mailingAddress = ((org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode)innerTable.select("tr:nth-child(4) > td > strong").first().nextSibling()).text();
```

First, you select the `table`, then you select the `strong` tag in the first `td` in the third `tr`, then you pick the next sibling to that, you take the `text()` in it and you are done. We do the same for the forth `tr`.

With `text()` JSoup will translate the `&nbsp;` into spaces, if you prefer not, you can also call `toString()`.

Hope that it helps.

PS: Can I suggest a trick? You can use developer tools of Chrome or Firefox to find a tag in a html page, then right click and `Copy CSS Path`. This will give you the selector you can use in JSoup!

Comment: Thank you! That is super helpful! I had no idea you could do that in browser to get those tags.